# Syncing Heroku and localhost databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, passwords, localhost, heroku-postgres

Hey so I am following the One Month Rails guide to learning Ruby and I have hit a wall on one of the lessons. I have just finished uploading an image with Paperclip, and as I finished my work on my localhost and checked it on Heroku, something went wrong. The pin/image appears to have been pushed to my Heroku account, the only problem is that the username and password that works for my localhost:3000 won't work for my Heroku account. The same password should work for both, but for some reason something is wrong. I wish I could give you the action that is going on in my terminal, but the ruby rails is the only thing that has a continuous status flow. The problem may have been when I switched my password after not using my account on localhost for a few weeks, but i thought that once i "git pushed" that to heroku master, it would've synced. I have tried heroku run rake db:setup which didn't seem to do too much as well as wrestled by way through "Importing a Heroku Postgres Database with PG Backups", but I had some trouble working through that. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'database.yml' should not be sent to Heroku, they take care of that, creating a new `database.yml` config file with the proper DB access details.

Try logging into your Heroku instance and deleting the file.

**Edit**: nevermind, assumed you were not able to connect to the DB, not to login into the website.

Comment: they rewrite the file, it doesn't matter if it's deployed to Heroku

Comment: Yeah I can connect to my heroku app on the server, it's - http://secret-tor-8794.herokuapp.com/. I am just unable to login to it. For some reason there is a different password for my heroku than there is for my localhost.

Comment: Wait, what if your app just updated the scaffolding but didn't actually copy any of the data inserted after deploying. Try creating your account again.

Comment: My heroku account? I mean it has worked before to login on heroku a while back, maybe i'm wrong though..

Comment: Hey Derek I really appreciate your help thank you. Would you happen to have any other ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Meant to say to try to register to your own test page again

Comment: Yeah that's a good call. I just tried to do that, but it came up with invalid email or password once again... I really appreciate you sticking with this for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding you correctly, you've deployed your application to Heroku and the login (to your application) that was working locally doesn't work on Heroku.

Deploying your application doesn't deploy data. Assuming you've run `heroku run rake db:migrate` then your database schemas will at least match.

At this point, you've got a couple of options.

1. Use a seeds.rb file which you can load with `heroku run db:seed` to setup some 'seed' data so that you can login.
2. Push your local database to Heroku - either via `heroku db:push` or using `heroku pg:transfer` provided by https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer
3. Use `heroku run console` to create your user account via the command line

   User.create(email: 'someemail.com', password: 'somepassword', password_confirmation: 'somepassword')

I'd be inclined to go with the later option.

How did the user get in their in the first place? Perhaps going back to that step in the tutorial - just remember, if you are using `rails console` locally to use `heroku run console` on Heroku.

Comment: So I tried option 1 and the terminal said that the command wasn't found. Then I tried option number 2 and it said "sudo gem install taps", but one of the other stackoverflow questions told some guy not to use sudo if he has RVM which is what I believe I have. So that's where I stopped with that one. Then I tried the second part to option 2 but it aborted the pg_dump because of an error and the input file was too short or something. Finally I tried the third option, but it said - syntax error near unexpected token `email:' - I then reexamined the tutorial, and I still haven't found the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help John, thank you. Would you happen to have any other ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: so how did the user get in there in the first place?

Comment: i used the signup button, or so i thought, but now it won't even let me make another one which is weird... i don't know if there is a problem with the development and production stage in my sublime or what. let me know what you think. I am really thankful that you're sticking with this to help me

Comment: i also told derek below that i have tried to sign up for another account, but even that doesn't work..